# {% with %} templatetag to avoid query execution multiple times?

Tags: django, django-templates

If I use for example `{{ some_model.objects.all }}` in several places in one template, will the query be executed each time? And if so, should I always use `{% with some_model.objects.all as some_name %}` to avoid that? I saw this in several apps, so I'm wondering if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does repeat the query. You should populate the context in your view instead of calling these functions within the template.

Using `{% with %}` indeed does solve the problem though for future calls, but I still vote for the view.

PS: 
I highly suggest downloading django-debug-toolbar
https://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar

You can test these ideas in a second : )

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I really like to call some functions within template, it's just very convenient, especially at design stage, becouse I don't have to edit the view each time, when I'm changing  template logic. Is there any reasonable explanation for not doing so, or the only reason is, that it's against mvc pattern?